# How can I run a command (a script) after boot?

Tags: scripts, automation

I want to run a simple command after boot.

```
cd /mypath
# then
./mycommand
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

The first one is to put the full path of the command in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/mypath/mycommand
```

or, the cron way:

`crontab -e`

```
@reboot cd /mypath;./mycommand
```

From the crontab manual:

```
 @reboot        Run once, at startup.
```

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is available for 16.04, but 17.10 and 18.04 aren't at least you make it available for systemd.